# Is the 6-torus a calabi-yau 3-fold?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am a confused about calabi-yau (CY) manifolds. In particular is a Torus $T^6$, viewed as $\mathbb{C}^3/\Lambda$ for some lattice lambda, a CY 3-fold?

If so, how can I see this?

I am doubting this is true, because I read that the hodge numbers of CY 3-folds must satisfy $h^{2,0}=h^{0,2}=0$, however the hodge number $h^{p,q}$ of the complex torus $\mathbb{C}^n/\Lambda$ is $h^{p, q}=C_p^n C_q^n$ ([$h^{p,q}$ of a complex torus.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3795327/hp-q-of-a-complex-torus)), which gives $h^{2,0}=1$.

Comment: As Wikipedia explains, there are several inequivalent definitions of Calabi-Yau manifolds in the literature (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold#Definitions). I guess $6$-tori satisfy some of them but not others. They clearly have a Ricci-flat metric, right?